# some site can't be crawled via curl php whereas it works with curl

Tags: php, curl

I tried to curl http://marinas.com with curl php :

```
$url = 'http://marinas.com';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

That doesn't return anything. Though it works if I try with other sites, google.com for instance.

And, curl http://marinas.com directly into the CLI works to…

It's a mystery for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a user agent when making the request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

This site does not respond to requests without a user agent. The above setting grabs the user agent of your browser and sends it to the target website.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks, I didn't think about that. I just manually entered a user agent as $_SERVER obviously doesn't work under php-cli. Thank you again